# Chaining/Nesting promises

Tags: javascript, promise, aws-sdk

I'm having nightmare trying to chain aws js sdk. Currently I have the following (omitted any parameters to remove chaff, the calls work in isolation so its safe to assume they are correct)

```
function deploy() {
  return sts.assumeRole().promise()
    .then(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          AWS.config.update({
            credentials: {
              accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
              secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
              sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
            }
          });
        resolve();
        })
        .then(() => {
          fsPromise.readFile(packageLocation).then(() => {
            return s3.upload().promise();
          });
        });
    }).then(() => {
      return ebs.createApplicationVersion().promise();
    }).then(() => {
      return ebs.createEnvironment().promise();
    });
};
```

If I run each `then` one by one in order it works, however when i run them together the `createApplicationVersion` call fails as the `upload` hasn't worked due to the fact it is attempting to upload before `assumeRole` has finished. I assume...

I am obviously doing something wrong, but It isn't clear to me what.

Comment: *"due to the fact it is attempting to upload before `assumeRole` has finished"* No, we can be sure that `assumeRole` is done before anything else above happens.

Comment: Does `AWS.config.update()` do its work asynchronously? Does it return a promise? (Or does it have this `.promise()` function on its return that you're using elsewhere?) Because nothing is waiting for that `update` to complete, if it's asynchronous.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder AWS.config.update() is setting some local variables, in the full length version of the code I have that wrapped in another promise, updated question

Comment: Don't worry, if it's just setting variables and not doing anything asynchronous, we don't need the details of it. And if it's doing synchronous work, there's no reason to wrap a promise around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of promises there is much more complicated than necessary. Remember that `then` (and `catch` and `finally`) **return new promises** that are settled based on what their handlers return. `new Promise` within a `then` (or `catch` or `finally`) handler is almost never necessary; just return whatever you would resolve that promise with (a value or another promise), and the promise returned by `then` et. al. will be resolved to it.

That chain should look like this, if I assume `AWS.config.update()` is synchronous:

```
function deploy() {
  return sts.assumeRole().promise()
    .then(() => {
        AWS.config.update();
    })
    .then(() => fsPromise.readFile(packageLocation))
    .then(() => s3.upload().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createApplicationVersion().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createEnvironment().promise());
}
```

Each step in that chain will wait for the previous step to complete.

If you don't want `deploy` to fulfill its promise with the fulfillment value of `ebs.createEnvironment().promise()`, then add a final `then` handler:

```
    .then(() => ebs.createEnvironment().promise())
    .then(() => { });
}
```

(I'll assume you want to do that for the following examples.)

Or like this if `AWS.config.update()` is asynchronous and returns a promise:

```
function deploy() {
  return sts.assumeRole().promise()
    .then(() => AWS.config.update())
    .then(() => fsPromise.readFile(packageLocation))
    .then(() => s3.upload().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createApplicationVersion().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createEnvironment().promise())
    .then(() => { });
}
```

Or, of course, in any relatively recent version of Node.js (I'm guessing from `fsPromise` and just general context that this is Node.js), you could use an `async` function:

```
async function deploy() {
  await sts.assumeRole().promise();
  await AWS.config.update(); // Or without `await` if it is synchronous and doesn't return a promise
  await fsPromise.readFile(packageLocation);
  await s3.upload().promise();
  await ebs.createApplicationVersion().promise();
  await ebs.createEnvironment().promise();
}
```

---

Side note about this code, and code like it you posted in a comment:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  AWS.config.update({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    }
  });
  resolve();
})
```

There's no reason to use `new Promise` there. It doesn't convert the call to `AWS.config.update` into an asynchronous call or anything like that. **If** for some reason you needed a promise there (you don't in this case, AKAICT), you'd use `Promise.resolve`:

```
AWS.config.update(/*...*/);
return Promise.resolve();
```

But again, no need for that here. Remember that promises only provide a way to *observe the result* of an asynchronous process, they don't make a process asynchronous. (The only thing that they actually make asynchronous is observing the result.)

Comment: Awesome answer thanks, one question, I need to pass the response from assumeRole into AWS.config.update, thats why I had it nested within the assume role promise?

Comment: @TomRiley - Glad that helped. No problem passing the result into `update`, just replace that line with ```.then(result => { AWS.config.update(/*...you can use `result` here...*/); })```

Comment: @TomRiley - For the `async` function version: ```const result = await sts.assumeRole().promise();``` then ```AWS.config.update(/*...you can use `result` here...*/);```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to nest your promises the way that you did. Taking a stab in the dark, try this:

```
function deploy() {
  return sts.assumeRole().promise()
    .then(() => { AWS.config.update() })
    .then(() => fsPromise.readFile(packageLocation))
    .then(() => s3.upload().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createApplicationVersion().promise())
    .then(() => ebs.createEnvironment().promise())
};
```

Comment: There's no reason for the `new Promise` part there.